# How to use binary search on 2 tables of sorted data in c

Tags: c, search, sorting, binary-search

I am looking into how to use binary search in the c language.

I will begin with,

i have a struct

```
struct keyval{
unsigned short key[2];
unsigned short val[2];
};
```

as you can see this is a struct with 2 arrays of shorts which can hold 2 short values.

i then memory allocate to these structs. this enables me to store many of this type of struct in memory.

```
struct keyval *codes1 = malloc(sizeof(struct keyval)*(0x1000000));
struct keyval *codes2 = malloc(sizeof(struct keyval)*(0x1000000));
```

I go through some loops and populate codes1 with struct keyval's. and then in another loop i populate codes2 with struct keyval's also

this data will have been populated on the basis of an iterating key. so basically it will be automatically sorted by key value.

i then sort my data on the `val` value . using the c qsort function
and my own compare function
if the short in location 0 of the val array of one is less than the short in the same position of the other struct then return -1 and so on.

```
qsort(codes1,SIZE_OF_CODES1, sizeof(struct keyval), compare);
qsort(codes2,SIZE_OF_CODES2, sizeof(struct keyval), compare);

int compare(const void *a, const void *b){
    struct keyval *ia = (struct keyval *)a;
    struct keyval *ib = (struct keyval *)b;

    if(ia->val[0] > ib->val[0]){
        return 1;
    }else if (ia->val[0] < ib->val[0]){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return (ia->val[1] - ib->val[1]);
    }
```

}

now this is where i am stuck

i need to be able to binary search for every value in codes1 against the values in codes2.
and when `codes1[i].val == codes2[i].val` i can print out the values of codes1[i].key 
and then codes2.[i].key

my attempt is as such

```
while(e <= SIZE_OF_CODES1){

    struct keyval *found = (struct keyval*) bsearch(&codes1[e],codes2,SIZE_OF_CODES2,sizeof(struct keyval),compare );

    if(found){
        printf("\n found key = %08x %04x value = %04x %04x", found -> key, found -> key[1],found->val[0],found ->val[1] );
    }

    e++;
}
```

the above code will not find if the data matches as, i am certain there are places in the code where it matches

//added edit

---

just did a debug, and i found that when the bsearch calls the compare function,everytime it is called all the values associated with ia are zero but ib is correct.

the sort method is correct

---

could someone point me in the right direction on how to implement a binary search , i am getting very stuck

my old compare function

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b){
struct keyval *ia = (struct keyval *)a;
struct keyval *ib = (struct keyval *)b;

if(ia->val[0] > ib->val[0]){

    return 1;
}else if(ia->val[0] < ib->val[0]){
    return -1;
}else{
    if(ia->val[1] > ib->val[1]){
        return 1;
    }else if(ia->val[1] < ib->val[1]){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 0;
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Does `codes1Counter == SIZE_OF_CODES2`? (You're using codes1Counter in your second qsort.) I'd start by putting breakpoints in compare once you get to the bsearch and watching what it's doing.

Comment: yes i changed the code there to match

Comment: just did a debug, and i found that when compare is called in the binary search the values of ia [0] and [1] are always zero,  but when i do it with the qsort the values are correct. but ib is correct

Comment: In bsearch the first argument of compare is the one you're searching in the array. So if it's always zero (in "compare") for the first bsearch call only it's ok, otherwise you're probably passing always the same element to search.

Comment: BTW, I tested your code and it works fine on my pc...

Comment: i cant get it to work, but if wanted to write my own simple bsearch . could i?

Comment: Sure, of course - you understand the principle, right? (If not, you really should read up on it - I've lost count the number of times binary search has come up somehow in an interview.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm. There's a pseudo-code sample at the end (obviously where you see `>` or `<` you must opportunely replace them with your `compare` )

Comment: Anyway, the C bsearch is fine, and should work. If it doesn't work, your problem is elsewhere. (P.S. `while(e <= SIZE_OF_CODES1)` is wrong, actually should be `<` not `<=`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to compare the lists as you describe, step through codes1, then do a bsearch() on codes2 for each entry in codes1.  You can reuse compare.  I am not sure if SIZE_OF_CODES1 and 2 are variables or defines, I am assuming they reflect the count of elements in each array.

```
struct keyval *src=codes1;
struct keyval *dest=code2;
struct keyval *p
int i=0;
while(i< SIZE_OF_CODES1)
{
    if( (p=(struct keyval *)bsearch(src, dest, SIZE_OF_CODES2, sizeof(struct keyval), compare))!=NULL)
        printf("duplicate codes1: %d %d  codes2: %d %d\n", src->key,src->val, p->key, p->val);
    i++
}
```

Comment: Which yields `nlogn` complexity. Is this really the best we can do? I doubt, since this is the also possible when only one of arrays is sorted. My gut tells me that having both of them sorted could give better complexity.

Comment: @Kos: yes it's possible in `O(2(m+n))` for example, as implemented in cpp stl `set_intersection` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/. Anyway, if I undestood correctly, the problem is not how to find the best method, but rather find why the current OP method don't work.

Comment: The question was: how to implement a binary search.  The best algorithm is to sort lists into one array, maintaining a source indicator, then make a single pass thru the array to find duplicates. But that was not what was asked.  And I assumed codes2 was sorted or a binary search would not be feasible.